# SwiftUi - Navigation View - How to show two views on iPad

Tags: ipad, swiftui, navigationview

I would like the iPad to show my first view1 list in the side bar and a second view alongside, populated by whatever is selected in view1. Then, when selecting something from the view2 list. go to the third view in full screen.

In my simple example, on loading I just get a blank screen with "< Back".  On click, I get a side bar with my view1, but nothing else.

Obviously doing something wrong. Grateful for help.

My example:

```
struct firstView: View {

let myFirstArray = [
    "First",
    "Second",
    "Third"
]

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List(myFirstArray, id: \.self) { value in
            NavigationLink (destination: SecondView()) {
                Text("FirstView \(value)")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("First View", displayMode: .inline)
        }
      }
   }
}

struct SecondView: View {

  let mySecondArray = [
      "One",
      "Two",
      "Three"
  ]

  var body: some View {
    List (mySecondArray, id: \.self) { value in
      NavigationLink (destination: ThirdView()) {
         Text("Second View \(value)")
      }
    }
  }
}

 struct ThirdView: View {

  var body: some View {
    Text("Hello World")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide default detail view for double column navigation view style (which you see as default for iPad - different sidebar visibility for portrait/landscape orientation)

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List(myFirstArray, id: \.self) { value in
            NavigationLink (destination: SecondView()) {
                Text("FirstView \(value)")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("First View", displayMode: .inline)
        }
        SecondView()    // << here !!
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you expand on the example please.  If I do as you have suggested, I get the SecondView displayed with "< Back" navigation which takes me to the FirstView

Comment: Rotate device to landscape orientation.

Comment: It has to be used in portrait